# Close Firefox download file popup from extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox extension. The extension opens a tab and loads some URL.
If it links to a file with specific MIME type (zip, flv) the the FF opens a download dialog.
How can I close this window?
If I use `gBrowser.addProgressListener(nsIWebProgressListener)` I can stop loading page but I can't close a window. 
I try to use `nsIURIContentListener` interface, but this interface works only when MIME type is not standart, when it is **text/html** it doesn't work.

relevant link: [Intercepting URL in Firefox extension](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=501254&sid=a2f27a7ca70ecb78ef834d80ec86286e)